# Dataset holds a table called "Table", not the table I pass in?

Tags: c#

I have the code below:

```
string SQL = "select * from " + TableName;

using (DS = new DataSet())
using (SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter())
using (SqlConnection sqlconn = new SqlConnection(connectionStringBuilder.ToString()))
using (SqlCommand objCommand = new SqlCommand(SQL, sqlconn))
{
    sqlconn.Open();
    adapter.SelectCommand = objCommand;
    adapter.Fill(DS);
}

System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show(DS.Tables[0].TableName);

return DS;
```

However, every time I run this code, the dataset (DS) is filled with one table called "Table". It does not represent the table name I pass in as the parameter TableName and this parameter does not get mutated so I don't know where the name Table comes from. I'd expect the table to be the same as the tableName parameter I pass in?

Any idea why this is not so?

EDIT: Important fact: This code needs to return a dataset because I use the dataRelation object in another method, which is dependent on this, and without using a dataset, that method throws an exception. The code for that method is:

```
DataRelation PartToIntersection = new DataRelation("XYZ", 
        this.LoadDataToTable(tableName).Tables[tableName].Columns[0],
        // Treating the PartStat table as the parent - .N
        this.LoadDataToTable("PartProducts").Tables["PartProducts"].Columns[0]);
        // 1

        // PartsProducts (intersection) to ProductMaterial
        DataRelation ProductMaterialToIntersection = 
           new DataRelation("", ds.Tables["ProductMaterial"].Columns[0],
                                ds.Tables["PartsProducts"].Columns[1]);
```

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The default name for the first table in the DataSet is `Table`, the second one will be called `Table1` and the third `Table2` and so forth. The DataSet will **not** read the table name from the underlying store - and there's no option to make it do so.

This is documented behavior - see the [MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bh8kx08z.aspx):

> If the DataAdapter encounters multiple
>   result sets, it creates multiple
>   tables in the DataSet. **The tables are
>   given an incremental default name of
>   TableN, starting with "Table" for
>   Table0.** If a table name is passed as
>   an argument to the Fill  method, the
>   tables are given an incremental
>   default name of TableNameN, starting
>   with "TableName" for TableName0.

If you want other names, you have to supply those - use this statement:

```
adapter.Fill(DS, Tablename);
```

This will name the newly filled table `Tablename` inside the DataSet.

Answer (score 1):

The [`DataTable.TableName`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable.tablename.aspx) is just the name associated with the runtime structure and is independent of the data source used to create the `DataTable`.